# PHPunit in zendframework 2

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2

i'm trying to use phpunit with zendframework and i'm follwing the tutorial in

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/zf2/latest/zf2.pdfhere is my

bootstrap.php

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
include __DIR__ . '/../init_autoloader.php';
```

here is my IndexControllerTest.php

```
<?php

namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class IndexControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
public function setUp()
{
$this->setApplicationConfig(
include '/C:/wamp/www/zf2/config/application.config.php'
);
    parent::setUp();
}

public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->dispatch('/'); // this is line 20
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);

    $this->assertModule('application');
    $this->assertControllerName('application_index');
    $this->assertControllerClass('IndexController');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('home');
}
}
```

and i'm getting the follwing errors

```
Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\zf2\module\Application\test/../init_autoloader.php)
: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\zf2\module\App
lication\test\Bootstrap.php on line 4


Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase'
not found in C:\wamp\www\zf2\module\Application\test\ApplicationTest\Controller
\IndexControllerTest.php on line 8
```

i think that's a path probleme (auloading)but i don't know how to fix

any one can help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\zf2\module\Application\test/../init_autoloader.php)
: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\zf2\module\App
lication\test\Bootstrap.php on line 4
```

This warning is telling you that it can't find the location of your `init_autoloader.php` file. Assuming that file is located in the root of your ZF2 project (so C:\wamp\www\zf2) as is convention, you need to change:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../init_autoloader.php';
```

to

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../../init_autoloader.php';
```

**EDIT** Continued...

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to 
load ZF2. Run php composer.phar install or define a ZF2_PATH environment 
variable.' in C:\wamp\www\zf2\init_autoloader.php:48
```

Your `init_autloader.php` file is having trouble finding your ZF2 library autoloader. As you're using composer. Add

```
"zendframework/zendframework": "2.1.*",
```

to your `"require"` section in composer.json if its not already there. Run composer and update your vendor libraries with

```
php composer.phar update
```

Try run the application again and see if it works. It may do depending what is included in your `init_autoload.php` file. If you're still having problems add the following to `init_autoloader.php`

```
if(file_exists('vendor/autoload.php'))
{
    $loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help , i dit as you told me and it seems that there is a problem with loading my module zf2


    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with   message 'Unable to load ZF2.    Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in C:\wamp\www\zf2\init_autoloader.php:48

have any idea where this is comming from ? my all others model are running fine with auloader

Comment: This fatal error shows it is having trouble finding your ZF2 library autoloader. Where is ZF2 located in your environment? Do you have a vendor folder? Are you using composer?

Comment: yes i'm using composer( i edited composer.json to install phpunit) , phpunit is installed in : C:\wamp\www\zf2\vendor
zf2 is located in : C:\wamp\www
PS: originally zf2 was named zend skeleton application (that you can download from zend website,then i named it to zf2 )


also i have composer folder located in C:\wamp\www\zf2\vendor , witch contains autoload_classmap.php  ,  autoload_namespaces.php , autoload_real.php, ClassLoader.php, include_paths.php   and installed.json  . 

thanks for your time i hope that we find a solution to this issue because i really tried my best without result :(

Comment: i did us you exactly tell me and still got the same error , i even reinstall zf2 and phpunit and wamp and every tool i used for my project .  i'm running out of solutions :((( any ideas ?

Comment: That exception is being thrown in your `init_autloader.php` file. Make sure that file looks like https://raw.github.com/akrabat/zf2-tutorial/master/init_autoloader.php. If you're still getting that error you need to check the path to your ZF2 library (not your ZF2 project). Do you have a vendor/zendframework folder? Can you find and give me the path to the `/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php` file. It should be in your ZF2 library folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Fix for the fatal error.

You must be missing the 'zend-test' package in your application.

> $ composer require zendframework/zend-test